# Memory Management in Objective-C, initializing a new array to an autoreleased array from another function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I'm trying to understand memory management better.  If I have a function that returns an autorelease NSArray like this

```
// DataClass
    - (NSArray *)getData {
       NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
       // do some stuff to get data from sqlite
       return array;
    }
```

then in another class file, I want to use this getData.  I have a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myData;

- viewDidLoad {
    NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    data = [DataClass getData];
    self.myData = data;
    [data release];
}
```

Why do I get a bad access error in this case?  I know it's because of [data release], but I thought that since the getData method returns an autorelease NSArray, and because I initialize a new NSMutableArray with alloc/init, then I'd need to release it?  Or is what happening is even though I initialize data with alloc/init, I then am not even using it because with the data=[DataClass getData] statement, I point to a different NSArray, and then try to release that already autoreleased NSArray from getData, and then the NSMutableArray data is still floating around in memory somewhere?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code can be written as `self.myData = [DataClass getData];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. :-)

First of all, as written, in `viewDidLoad` you leak the `data` you alloc/init on line 1 when you assign `data` the result of calling `getData` on line 2.

And then, you are correct, that `data` at this point is pointing at an autoreleased object. So calling `release` on it is a bad thing.

Frankly, in your `viewDidLoad` method, you really don't need the call to `getData` at all. The complete and appropriate sequence for this kind of operation is:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// here is where you could fill array with your data, or call a method to 
// which you pass array to be filled.
self.data = array;
[array release];
```

assuming that the data property is defined with `retain`. By using the `self.` prefix, you get a `retain` done for you.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems with your code. The first is certain:

```
 NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 data = [DataClass getData];
```

This is not the correct pattern for initializing objects. Let's assume a class method called `getData` exists, and does what you want (which may not be the case, more on that later). The first line would allocate memory for a new array, and return a pointer to it. The second line would then immediately reassign that pointer to point to a different (autoreleased) array, leaking the first array in the process.

Secondly, your `getData` method has the following signature:

```
- (NSArray *)getData;
```

Implying that it is an *instance* method, meaning you send it to an instance of the `DataClass`. However, your code that calls the method does so by sending the message to the class itself, not an instance of it. This may just be a typo in your posting, but better safe than sorry.